# Codeigniter 4 embedding CSS and JS file

Tags: javascript, css, codeigniter-4

I am new to Codeigniter and I am trying to use Codeigniter 4. What do I have to do in order for me to load my CSS and JS file? I have been spending for the past 7 hours trying to figure out what's wrong but still can't find any solution.

This is my folder structure:

```
-app
-public
--css
---styles.css
--js
---mainjs.js
--img
-system
-writable
```

The file is there and I even tried to put the exact path instead of using base_url but I keep getting either file not found error or internal server error message. The tutorial or guide I see on the net, all I saw was pointing the path to the file location and it works for them. There are limited answers posted here too which is based on Codeigniter 4.

```
.env file
 app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/ci/'


app/Controllers/Pages.php

<?php namespace App\Controllers;

class Pages extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }
    
    
    public function view($page)
    {
        if ( ! is_file(APPPATH.'/Views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException($page);
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        echo view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}

app/Views/templates/header.php

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('public/css/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
```

Hope there's someone here who can help me out on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CodeIgniter 4 uses htaccess file, to server the public content from the public folder. So the content such as css should be inside that particular folder. Lets say you have style.css file for serving css. Than it should be in public -> css -> style.css. And in your code you can use base_url/css/style.css to refer to your file.

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda thank you for your help. I have tried that too but it's still showing the same thing. I tried putting them in public folder instead of assets, it's not working too and I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Can you update the answer when you put files in the public folder and also include the code on how you are refering to those files ?

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda I have updated my questions already. Not sure whether is that ok. I have also included the base_url setting from my .env file. For the header, I even tried using the exact location instead of using base_url but the problem still persist.

Comment: echo base_url('http://localhost/ci/assets/css/style.css'); This seems to be the issue I would say. Most probably it will append localhost/ci Try out with a relative path. Also, you don't have assets folder. So remove the asset. Just use src='/css/style.css' (if you dont have assets folder in public)

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda  It's working now by changing it to src='/css/style.css' !!! I am speechless... So am I right to say that the right way now is putting css, js and image files will be in public folder in Codeigniter 4 instead of creating an assets folder like the previous version?

Comment: @Dhaval Chheda Oh and 1 more question. I am still confused. Based on my file path, by right, logically it's supposed to be http://localhost/ci/public/css/style.css. If I use base_url('css/style.css');, it returns the right path but return file not found message. If I use src='/css/style.css', it returns me http://localhost/css/style.css which is not the exact path but the system able to read the file. Why is that so? I don't get the logic, it's seems weird.

Comment: This may not be the best or the most accurate explaination but the way it works is, the htaccess file in the public folder, rewrites the url using the base domain name. In your case the base domain name is localhost. localhost/ci is a path on localhost domain. To make better sense you should use some custom url like example.com so it makes a better sense along with virutal host defined in apache server.

Answer (score 0):

because in your .env `app.baseURL = 'http://localhost/ci'` if u echo `base_url()` it will return **http://localhost/ci** as well so it assume that your public folder have **CI** folder inside that

- if you still want to use your current folder structure

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

- in your public folder structur there is no ci/assets folder so just put your style.css folder under ci/assets/css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>" type="text/css" media="all" />
```

Comment: You are missing a trailing / on app.baseURL which will cause cause your base_url('assets/css/style.css') to not work so well.

Comment: @nadim thanks for your help! But I tried all ways I can think of, it's still not working. Even I tried to access the file by entering http://localhost/ci/public/css/style.css in the browser, it still returns me file not found error.

Answer (score 0):

- you don't need to mention public folder
- you can make one assets folder in public folder and put your css and js file there
- path will be base_url('assets/css/style.css')